# Change Storyboard

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

i have a question:

I'm creating a slide in menu in Windows 8:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,-500" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="500" Height="500" Background="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
```

I have this animation:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ShowHideHelp">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="HideHelp"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="ShowHelp">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

How can i change TO property of my storyboard (**To="-500"**)? (highlighted)

```
<Storyboard> <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-500"....
```

Comment: may be this link would be helpful for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj819807.aspx

Comment: Do you want to change through code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

XAML

```xml
<Grid x:Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,-500" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="500" Height="500" Background="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ShowHideHelp">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="HideHelp"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="ShowHelp">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

C#

```csharp
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var storyboard = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this.grid).Get("ShowHideHelp").States.Get("ShowHelp").Storyboard;
    ((DoubleAnimation)(storyboard.Children[0])).To = 500;
}

public static class VisualStateExtensions
{
    public static VisualStateGroup Get(this IList<VisualStateGroup> stateGroups, string name)
    {
        return stateGroups.Single(x => x.Name == name);
    }

    public static VisualState Get(this IList<VisualState> stateGroups, string name)
    {
        return stateGroups.Single(x => x.Name == name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me, a little changed Xyroids code:

```
var storyboard = ShowHelp.Storyboard;
((DoubleAnimation)(storyboard.Children[0])).To = 500;
```